# Why did the old woman curse the servants of the French prince as well?

Tags: plot-explanation, beauty-and-the-beast

In the beginning of *Beauty and the Beast* (1991) the old beggar woman cursed the French prince because of his disrespect. His servants also turned into anthropomorphic household items like tea pots, clocks, etc.

[image]

Why did the old woman curse the servants of the French prince as well? What mistakes did they make?

Comment: _And as punishment, she transformed him into a hideous beast and placed a powerful spell on the castle and all who lived there._ It seems that the curse didn't "went on the servants", it was her deliberate choice to curse them as well. Perhaps they also mistreated her or she felt that if they are serving such a person they are deserving the same fate. Alternatively, in her anger she didn't think much and just cursed the prince and everything related to him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She cursed them together, not one after the other. This is because she most likely cursed his household not just himself. The servants would have been seen as his property. All the servants and their families would have been included.

Answer (score -1):

The original author of the story [Beauty and the Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_and_the_Beast) was Gabrielle-Suzanne Barbot de Villeneuve and published in 1740. Popular movies and stories refer to the  [Jeanne-Marie Leprince de Beaumont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanne-Marie_Leprince_de_Beaumont) who lived in France and England of the 18th century.  The views at the time, about belonging to a household, probably influenced her writing.

Comment: Does this happen in the original story, though? Were his servants bewitched and turned into household items there too? I forget.

Comment: I am not sure.  It turns out Jeanne-Marie's might not be the original after all.  See [Beauty and the Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_and_the_Beast) and [Movie Plot](http://moviepilot.com/posts/3386298).

Comment: @David The original is by Gabrielle-Suzanne Barbot de Villeneuve but was edited by Jeanne-Marie Leprince de Beaumont. The movie is based on Beaumont's story. Although in Beaumont's story there might not even be servants.  "For several months, Beauty lives a life of luxury at the Beast's palace, having every whim catered to by invisible servants..."

Comment: Thank you @OceanKnight. Yes, I noticed it and edited my answer.